# Hough Circle False Positve filtering

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to create a footfall counter. The currently I have apply a canny filter and they a hough circle transform is applied to detect circles. In the image below you can see random circles showing up which need to be filtered. I have read a couple scientific reports including this one, https://www.scitepress.org/papers/2010/28560/28560.pdf.

They mention a post processing technique called Gaussian mixture models (GMM), I am not familiar with this algorithm implementation in my code. If anyone could help me that would be great. I need some sort of filtering method that can filter out all circles and only detect the heads.

note: currently just use one input, I will be using stereo vision additionally for depth calculation. Could a depth map be used to filter out false positives, let me know!

Hough Circle detection:

[image: Hough Circle detection]

Canny filter:
[image: Canny filter]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time

def apply_canny_with_noise_reduction(image):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # Apply Gaussian blur for noise reduction
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (15, 15), 0)  # You can adjust the kernel size as needed
    edges = cv2.Canny(blurred, 50, 100)  # You can adjust these thresholds as needed
    return edges



# Function to apply Hough Circle Transform
def apply_HCT(image, edges, roi_areas):
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(edges, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, dp=5, minDist=100, param1=75, param2=80, minRadius=50, maxRadius=70) 
    # You can adjust these parameters as needed
    if circles is not None:
        circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
        for i in circles[0, :]:
            center = (i[0], i[1])
            # Check if the circle center falls within any of the ROI areas
            for roi_area in roi_areas:
                if center[0] >= roi_area[0] and center[0] <= roi_area[2] and center[1] >= roi_area[1] and center[1] <= roi_area[3]:
                    radius = i[2]
                    # Draw the circle
                    cv2.circle(image, center, radius, (0, 255, 0), 2)
                    break  # Break the loop if the circle is found within any ROI
    return image

# Function to exclude circles using GMM clustering
def exclude_circles(image):
    # Implement GMM clustering here to exclude circles
    # This part would require more detailed implementation based on your requirements
    return image

# Path to the video file
video_file = '/Users/admin/Desktop/test_vid.mp4'

# Read the video file
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_file)

# Variables for FPS calculation
start_time = time.time()
frame_count = 0

# Define multiple ROI areas [(x1, y1, x2, y2), ...]
roi_areas = [(100, 100, 700, 400), (700, 250, 900, 600)]

while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        break

    # Apply Canny edge detection
    edges = apply_canny_with_noise_reduction(frame)

    # Apply Hough Circle Transform
    circles_detected = apply_HCT(frame.copy(), edges, roi_areas)

    # Exclude circles using GMM clustering
    circles_excluded = exclude_circles(circles_detected)

    # Draw ROIs on the processed frame
    for roi_area in roi_areas:
        cv2.rectangle(circles_excluded, (roi_area[0], roi_area[1]), (roi_area[2], roi_area[3]), (255, 0, 0), 2)

    # Calculate FPS
    frame_count += 1
    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
    fps = frame_count / elapsed_time

    # Add FPS text to the frame
    fps_text = f"FPS: {fps:.2f}"
    cv2.putText(circles_excluded, fps_text, (10, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 0, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

    # Display the processed frame
    cv2.imshow('Processed Frame', circles_excluded)

    # Display the edges
    cv2.imshow('Canny Edges', edges)  
    
    # Press 'q' to exit
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Tried playing with the thresehold levels of the HCT. Found if too high heads are not detected.

Comment: What does your Canny image look like?  Canny is not generally recommended to find circles.

Comment: Here is the Image. If not canny what else filter to use?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyKHy.png

Comment: From the HoughCircles documentation: "Finds circles in a grayscale image using the Hough transform."  Convert your image to grayscale or choose some single channel in BGR or HSV that best shows the circles you want. Or threshold on the color of the object that is the circle(s).

Comment: Can you post the original image?